# maximum file size for $file->write

Tags: php, cakephp, csv

I’m currently working on a cleanup shell script (in cakephp) that processes csvs and exports again as csvs to be imported into another site.

I’ve noticed that there appears to be a maximum limit of around 2500 lines that i can write into a file before it stops writing, which relates to around 4.5MB.

Is it possible to increase this write limit and if so where would that change be made?

Thanks

Comment: please provide the code-snippet which writes to the file... I think you are running out of memory before you are done writing the file (keeping everything in 1 big array for example)

Comment: Thanks @RichardBernards. It appears my issue was elsewhere. I'm using the CsvDatasource but not switching correctly between my files. $this->setSource($filename) to switch files rather than $this->useTable = $filename; Thanks for your help.